# How can i refresh pictureBox by button?

Tags: c#

I have a pictureBox and a button on my form. Button is just refreshing pictureBox. When pictureBox is refreshing it’s drawing line at the pictureBox.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox.Refresh();
}
```

And i set OnPaint event for my PictureBox, so when my pictureBox is redrawing its call this method:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //logic for drawing line
        //its not so important, cause even if i put messagebox.show, result is the same.
    }
```

I spend whole day to figure out why after pressing the button, line is not appear at the picture box. Turns out that program do like that：

1) button_click -> 2)pictureBox_Paint -> 3) button_click (again!!)

How its even possible? What should i do to just implement logic:

1) button_click -> 2)pictureBox_Paint

Comment: Do not call `Paint` directly. Call `pictureBox1.Refresh()`.

Comment: @LouisGo thanks for comment. I do the same, but don't know why, but programm behave uncorectly.

Comment: Just for my curiosity is the same if you call that method from mouse up event instead click?

Comment: The Button `Click` handler is not called twice, it simply re-enters the handler method after you have refreshed the PictureBox. `Control.Refresh()` simply calls `Invalidate(true)` and `Update()`, meaning, the PictureBox is repainted immediately. Call `PictureBox.Invalidate()` instead, when needed. Invalidate enqueues a paint message, which will be executed *later*.

Comment: @Jimi thank you for your explanations, i understand how it works now! But, unfortunately, behavior of my program remain the same.

Comment: @StefanoCavion yeap, looks like the same, if i understand you right.

Comment: You need to post the code that draws this line.